# Convert sums of row data, with conditions, into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to get sums of row data into columns but can't get it to work.
This returns 60 rows, with the correct sum in one of the rows for each of the three columns (image below). All other values returned are NULL:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'January' AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END 'January 2023 Count',
    CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'February' AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END 'February 2023 Count',
    CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'March' AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END 'March 2023 Count'   --etc.
FROM employees e
JOIN file_load f ON f.guid = e.guid
GROUP BY e.guid, f.month_period, f.year_period
```

Results:

[image]

But if I try this, I get the single row that I'm looking for but obviously only the 'January' column has the sum data in it:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'January' AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END 'January 2023 Count',
    CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'February' AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END 'February 2023 Count',
    CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'March' AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END 'March 2023 Count'   --etc.
FROM employees e
JOIN file_load f ON f.guid = e.guid
WHERE f.month_period = 'January' AND f.year_period = 2023
GROUP BY e.guid, f.month_period, f.year_period
```

Results:

[image]

I haven't been able to find any way to add a WHERE clause or GROUP BY "within" the CASE WHEN expressions.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't conditionally use an aggregate function. In this case you just need to use a single SUM around the whole logic.

Slight detour...using string literals as a column alias is deprecated. Either wrap your column names in square brackets or even better, leave the formatting to the front end and remove the spaces and such from the column name.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'January' AND f.year_period = 2023 and e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'January 2023 Count',
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'February' AND f.year_period = 2023 and e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'February 2023 Count',
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'March' AND f.year_period = 2023 and e.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'March 2023 Count'   --etc.
FROM employees e
JOIN file_load f ON f.guid = e.guid
WHERE f.month_period = 'January' AND f.year_period = 2023
GROUP BY e.guid, f.month_period, f.year_period
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are using is called *conditional aggregation*. It is an alternative and sometimes more flexible way to perform a `PIVOT`.

When using conditional aggregation, you need to code the entire condition in a `CASE` expression or `IIF()` function wrapped up by the aggregate function. You would also omit the associated criteria columns from the `GROUP BY` clause.

I believe what you need is something like:

```
SELECT
    e.guid,
    e.name,
    e.status,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'January'  AND f.year_period = 2023 AND e.status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [January 2023 Count],
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'February' AND f.year_period = 2023 AND e.status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [February 2023 Count],
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'March'    AND f.year_period = 2023 AND e.status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [March 2023 Count]   --etc.
FROM employees e
JOIN file_load f ON f.guid = e.guid
GROUP BY e.guid, e.name, e.status
ORDER BY e.name
```

I've included `e.guid`, `e.name`, and `e.status` in both the select list and the group-by clause.

Sample results:

| guid | name | status | January 2023 Count | February 2023 Count | March 2023 Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27bdb8c9-b7b7-404d-a69a- 9244b3f158f9 | Emp 1 | A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 6fcc0000-5fb2-4142-ac8c- f9e1edb6c917 | Emp 2 | X | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4fe0c2e2-a08c-4b58-9d8a- 32a75db372dd | Emp 3 | A | 2 | 0 | 4 |

If you just want counts, you can also use `COUNT(CASE condition THEN 1 END)`. If the condition is true, the `THEN 1` is counted. If false, the implied `ELSE NULL` is not counted.

For this sample query, it mioght also be appropriate you can move the `e.status = 'A'` to a `WHERE` clause.  This would exclude the "Emp 2" row from the above results.

The query would then be something like:

```
SELECT
    e.guid,
    e.name,
    e.status,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'January'  AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN 1 END) [January 2023 Count],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'February' AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN 1 END) [February 2023 Count],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.month_period = 'March'    AND f.year_period = 2023 THEN 1 END) [March 2023 Count]   --etc.
FROM employees e
JOIN file_load f ON f.guid = e.guid
WHERE e.status = 'A'
GROUP BY e.guid, e.name, e.status
ORDER BY e.name
```

Results:

| guid | name | status | January 2023 Count | February 2023 Count | March 2023 Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27bdb8c9-b7b7-404d-a69a- 9244b3f158f9 | Emp 1 | A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4fe0c2e2-a08c-4b58-9d8a- 32a75db372dd | Emp 3 | A | 2 | 0 | 4 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u-eCCN7K) for a demo.

Comment: Don't think I was clear in what I'm looking for here. I just want a count of all the records in the employee table that meet the criteria (month, year, status of 'A').
Results will return just one row with columns for each month/year that is called out in the SELECT statement. Thanks for any additional info you can provide!

Comment: @user1646210 - I was attempting to show a more generalized usage. Just drop the `GROUP BY`, 'ORDER BY' and employee columns from the query. That will yield a single-row, combined result.

Comment: @T N - Ahh I get it. This is perfect. Thanks so much!